# Extract text from a font tag on nodeJs

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio, puppeteer

I'm using `Cheerio` to extract informations from html code of different webpages.
However there is a website in which the text that I wanna extract is included in a script tag; therefore that piece of code wasn't accessible by `Cheerio` methods.

So, looking for a solution, I found on the web the possibility to run that script using puppeteer, that is an API node to handle a chrome instance.
Using this, even if not in the best way because I discovered it some days ago, finally I obtained the html code that I need. 
Unfortunately I am not able to extract the information that I need.
This is the html code from which I wanna extract the data:

```
<h2 class="property-price">
  <a href="blablabla">
    <strong>
      <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
        <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Text that I wanna extract</font>
      </font>
      <small></small>
    </strong>
  </a>  
</h2>
```

This is instead the code that I used to extract the text data without success:

```
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var $;
const POST_LINK_SELECTOR = 'div.property-title';

(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('myUrl',{
    timeout: 0
  });
  $=cheerio.load(renderedContent);
  console.log($('h2.property-price').find('font').children().text());
  await browser.close();
})();
```

I'm sure that this is not the best way to obtain the data text that I need, so if you have some suggestions I will acccept them happily.
Furthermore I would know if is possible to extract what I need using directly the puppeteer API or if I need to use `Cheerio`(like I did in my case and that anyway doesn't work).
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the needed data right with the puppeteer, with the help of `page.evaluate` method:

```
(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('myUrl',{waitUntil: "networkidle0"});

    const text = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector("h2.property-price a").textContent.trim() )
    console.log(text);

    await browser.close();
})();
```

If you'd like to continue using jQuery-like syntax of Cheerio, that can be done too, just add jQuery to the page (if the site doesn't use it aready)

```
await page.goto(...);
await page.addScriptTag({url: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'});
```

Comment: ok it is works for the text. Just i wanna ask you if there are other ways to do this because is too slow in my case.

Comment: Slow as compared to cheerio? By how much?

Comment: yes. It takes literally 2 minutes to retrieve the text (if i setup headless: true, else 30 seconds more or less). In the meantime i'm trying to see on the web other headlessBrowser but honestly i don't know which is the best now.

Comment: That's terribly slow. You should launch puppeteer in headful mode with DevTools enabled and watch in Network panel what takes so long to load. (Probably ads and social network widgets) Then turn on request intercepting and cancel requests to those sites.

Comment: Honestly i don't have idea how to do it. If you know some guides or if you could write some lines of codes to explain would help me.

Comment: i'm trying with casperjs for the moment and for this kind of operations is faster than puppeteer. But with another website, with puppeteer (in headless: false) i'm able to retrieve the informations, instead casperjs spend too much time. I'm so confused now.

Comment: But does casperjs.do the job in the long run?

Comment: For the question that i did in this page casperjs retrieves the data in a faster time than puppeteer. But for another website scraping it requires too much time, more than puppeteer (that anyway requires much time in headless mode). So i would like to know if there are some solutions to reduce this delays and from what they are caused.

Comment: I fixed the problem reading in thi webPage https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1718. It's enough to add this arguments within the launch() method: {args: ["--proxy-server='direct://'", '--proxy-bypass-list=*']}

Comment: Good god what a weird bug, great that you've figured it out!